# labview truth table combination

Tags: combinations, labview

i want to create truth table combination depends on input like, if one input then just two combination 0 and 1 and if two input then combinations are 00, 10, 01, 11 and the inputs are N so it creates depends on input number

Comment: The text of this question is nearly impossible to read. Please fix the grammar/capitalization/punctuation to make it legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple VI that gives an String-Array of the binary numbers. 
It simply goes through all numbers from (2^n)-1 to zero and converts the numbers to strings with n letters.
I hope, it helps you. :)

In future questions, please provide some more information:
- What is your current effort regarding the Question (what have you tried)?
- What type do you want the output to be?

[image]